# Post clicked #id to a modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, zurb-foundation

I am trying to post the ID of the clicked element that triggers the modal to the modal.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
//reveal Modal when when clicking on an item box.
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.items').click(function() {
        function post(){
            $.post("/includes/functions/choose_item.php",{
                id:this.id
            });
        }
        $('#choose_item_modal').foundation('reveal', 'open', post());
    });
});
```

And this is the code of the file I am opening:

```
echo $_POST["id"];
```

How should i write the JavaScript so it would be able to post the ID of the element I am clicking on? 
It is made in Foundation 5.

Comment: `$('#choose_item_modal').foundation('reveal', 'open', post());` do you want to call this after sending the id?

Comment: I am trying to send the ID with it, is that possible? or should i first post and then call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first send the id then call this statement in callback function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.items').click(function() {
        function post(){
            $.post("/includes/functions/choose_item.php",{
                id:this.id
            },function(result){
 $('#choose_item_modal').foundation('reveal', 'open', post());
});
        }
    });
});
```

you are not receiving the value because `$('#choose_item_modal').foundation('reveal', 'open', post());` is called before the post method completes , it is not waiting to complete the post method sends the value and then call it.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thought I could do it like I did. 
How should I do it then? When I add your code in that doesn't work too.

Comment: So have been trying some stuff, and still not able to make it work. How should I build it so post is first?

Answer (score 0):

try this

for get id of element `$(this).attr("id")`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.items').click(function() {
        var id=$(this).attr("id");
        function post(){
            $.post("/includes/functions/choose_item.php",{
                id:id
            });
        }
        $('#choose_item_modal').foundation('reveal', 'open', post());
    });
});
```

Comment: It did not work. 
I tried to add just an test echo in the choose_item.php, and that one doesn't get echoed too.

Comment: use alert(id); this return value?

Comment: Yes, and also does this.id, that part is not the part i can't get to work. It is the whole posting something to a modal.